# Keep camel route active during a specific time range

Tags: design-patterns, timer, routes, cron, apache-camel

I have a camel route consuming a JMS queue.
Now I have to ensure, this route only runs during a specific time range and is stopped otherwise.

What would be the best design pattern for that?
I can't find an appropriate enterprise pattern or component option.

My idea is a quartz-job which start/stops the route.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html

You can write a cron expression and add that to your route startup policy.

Comment: A RoutePolicy ... that's it. Thank you. My brain is still sleeping...too early this morning.